# Diferença de tempo entre datas em JavaScript e MySQL

Tags: javascript, datetime, data

Tenho `data_inicio` e `data_fim` e quero saber a diferença de horas e minutos entre elas. A `data_inicio` já vai estar salva no banco MySQL como `datetime`,  `data_fim` vai pegar a data do momento em que o usuário clicar em um botão. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Converter `data_inicio` em milisegundos, comparar com `data_inicio` e depois formatar o resultado para exibir em horas e minutos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript entente data no formato de milissegundos. Da forma que você pensou em fazer talvez dê certo, converter a `data_inicio` em mili. Mas Acho que converter de milissegundos para data seja mais fácil. Para lidar com data em javascript, recomendo [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/), que já possui várias funções prontas. Um exemplo é a diff (diferença):

```
var a = moment(1390310146.791877);
var b = moment(1390309386.271075);
a.diff(b)//Diferença em milliseconds
a.diff(b,'seconds')//Diferença em segundos
a.diff(b,'minutes')//Diferença em minutos
```

Comment: Vou usar o moment.js. Então eu consigo comparar as datas no formato salvo no banco no javascript sem conversão, por exemplo `2016-11-28 13:00:00`? Obrigado

Comment: Consegue sim. Na própria documentação tem alguns exemplos.

Comment: Muito bom, mas você vai carregar seu site com um plugin a mais sendo que não precisa... 
Mas a decisão é sua.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função do mysql [DATEDIFF()](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

(exemplos retirados da W3Schools)

Porém, ela retorna a diferença apenas em dias. Se precisa se algo mais preciso você pode fazer o cálculo de segundos, dessa forma:

Query:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(data_inicio) data_inicio, TIME_TO_SEC(data_fim) data_fim FROM tabela WHERE data_fim IS NOT NULL;
```

Javascript:

```
var diferenca = data_fim - data_inicio;
var diferenca_dias = round(diferenca/86400);
var diferenca_horas = round((diferenca%8400) / 3600);
var diferenca_minutos = round(((diferenca%8400)%3600)/60);
var diferenca_segundos = round( (((diferenca%8400)%3600)%60)/60);
```